# NAS won't auto-mount at boot + qBittorrent issues

Tags: lubuntu, automount, nas, exfat, qbittorrent

I want to set up a low-powered system with a netbook (Eee PC) and a NAS for torrent purpose. I’ve made a clean install of Lubuntu 14.10 as I think it’s the best option for my machine (1GB RAM).
The netbook will stay connected 24/24h to the NAS (2x 3TB exFAT HDD).
I’ve managed to install exfat-nofuse (didn't manage to load it to the kernel though) and it seems working so far.
As torrent client I will use qBittorrent.

After few test I’ve found these issues:

1 • NAS auto-mount at boot won't work.
Every time I boot lubuntu I need to type: smb://192.168.1.3  to mount the NAS HDD (and the Volume will appear on the left bar).
What I want is to auto-detect the NAS at boot without doing it manually every time.

2 • qBittorrent autostart at boot not working.
I went to Preferences > Default applications for LXSession, then Autostart and manually added “qBittorrent” in Manual autostarted applications. I rebooted but it doesn’t work.

3 • qBittorrent doesn’t even check torrents.
From qBittorrent I added a couple of torrents that were already present into the NAS, but qBittorrent won’t even check them. Torrents status continue to stay Stalled. The Connection Status say I’ve no direct connections and it’s yellow. In the router I’ve opened the port 26777 on both TCP/UDP but still doesn’t work :(
I did the same test with Transmission and it checks the torrents flawlessly.

Regarding the first two points, I found Autofs for auto-mounting here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs. Would this work in my case with qBittorrent?

Basically I need qBittorrent to autostart at boot and to auto-detect the HDD inside the NAS for seeding the torrents.

Answer (score 0):

You have three questions here that really should be posted separately.

For the issues with mounting the NAS..
If the NAS is sharing via SMB, you shouldn't need to account for whatever filesystem it's running on a client machine - the NAS box will handle the filesystem overhead. Adding an entry in `/etc/fstab` to connect to the NAS at boot should solve the problem of getting the volume to mount. Read the [fstab documentation here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) on how to configure.

Comment: Thank you douggro for your link. I’m a beginner and for me is not easy. I've solved point 2, I needed to add `@qbittorrent` instead.

So this is what I should do?

I need to modify  `/etc/fstab` and the string to add would be something like this:
`//192.168.1.3 /media/nas cifs user=user,uid=1000,gid=100  0  0`

So then I typed this to create credentials file:

`gksudo gedit /etc/samba/credentials`

It asks for my password but then when I go inside `/etc/samba` credentials is not there.

Comment: You can add the user/password pair as part of the `fstab` entry without having to edit anything with Samba credentials. There are also ways to use a hash file to store those `fstab` credentials if you're concerned about somebody accessing the `/etc/fstab` record.